# How do you protect certain php files from overwriting by updates in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have made some changes on a php file from a certain plug-in. How do I prevent their lost when someone else decide to update this plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to alter the plugin's behavior with a plugin of your own. But that depends on the nature of the *changes* you've done.

You can disable its update capabilities with the following filter:

```php
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['akismet/akismet.php'] );
    return $value;
}
```

There are a couple of other methods to deal with this in the Answer from where I copied this code:

#### [If I rename a plugin (in its main php file) do I still get update notifications?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56968/12615)